# Why is this the correct formula to update the NN weights in Q-learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, backpropagation, q-learning

I'm trying to implement Q-learning to train an AI bot to play Pokemon battles. Since there is a large state space (corresponding to all possible states a battle can have in between moves), I can't use tables, so I'm using (nonlinear) function approximation. I found [this](https://instructure-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/account_10020000000097009/attachments/64680933/rl-function-approximation.pdf?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22rl-function-approximation-1.pdf%22%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27rl%252Dfunction%252Dapproximation%252D1.pdf&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJDW777BLV26JM2MQ%2F20180906%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180906T012533Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=b14da2eda4a51b374608f0fa9082cc18bebaf22b218fd44afe3df733760441e1) formula to update the weights in a NN for Q, but I don't understand why it works:

$$
\theta_i \leftarrow \theta_i + \alpha \left( r + \beta \max_{a'} \hat{Q}(s', a') - \hat{Q}(s, a) \right) \frac{\partial \hat{Q}(s, a)}{\partial \theta_i}
$$

It seems related to backpropogation but I'm not sure how it's supposed to work. For example, there isn't an error function we're trying to minimize; the only feedback we get from the environment is the reward, and I don't see how updating the weights in this way is supposed to result in a closer approximation to the actual $Q(s, a)$. Can someone please translate this intuitively, or provide a proof of convergence? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The update formula in single-step Q learning is directly related to the [Bellman equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation) for optimal value function:

$$q(s,a) = \sum_{s',r}p(s',r|s,a)(r + \gamma \max_{a'}q(s',a'))$$

(NB the $\gamma$ here is the same as the $\beta$ in your update, it is the *discount factor*)

This applies to any finite Markov decision process, and can be derived simply from definitions of action value Q (expected *return* following a specific state, action pair) state transition and policy. The [policy improvement theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258607/policy-improvement-theorem) explains how this optimal equality can be approached by getting accurate estimates of Q under *any* policy, then altering the policy to be greedy with respect to the current Q values. Q learning combines evaluation and improvement steps, and is a stochastic sampling version of [value iteration](http://incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node44.html) that approaches this optimal equality for all states and actions in expectation.

When you add function approximation, and optimise by gradient descent, then there *is* an implied loss function for the approximation:

$$\overline{VE} = \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}} \sum_{a \in \mathcal{A}(s)} \mu(s,a)(q(s,a) - \hat{q}(s,a,\theta))^2$$

Where $\mu(s,a)$ is the relative proportion of time steps sampled in state $s$ and take action $a$, according to the *behaviour policy* (typically $\epsilon$-greedy policy over Q values). This proportion changes over time as the policy improves, so the distribution is non-stationary.

If you take the gradient w.r.t. $\theta$ for the above equation, you get:

$$\nabla \overline{VE} = 2 \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}} \sum_{a \in \mathcal{A}(s)} \mu(s,a)(\hat{q}(s,a,\theta) - q(s,a))\nabla \hat{q}(s,a,\theta)$$

Your update rule is stochastic gradient descent based on this, shown for one element of $\theta$.

Although this is the loss function that you are working to due to the update in Q learning, it is not necessarily the best loss function you could have. That is still a matter of research, and it is not clear how much weight it is worth putting on $s,a$ pairs that are not visited due to the *current* behaviour policy for instance, in order to avoid issues such as catastrophic forgetting.

In addition, you don't have access to the true value of $q(s,a)$ and are using the *bootstrap* estimate $r + \gamma \max_{a'}\hat{q}(s',a', \theta)$ for it instead.

Finally, the bootstrap value or *TD Target* is based on your estimator, which depends on $\theta$, but that is not being included in the gradient. That makes DQN a *semi-gradient* method.

> It seems related to backpropogation but I'm not sure how it's supposed to work.

There is no back propagation in the formula. However, if you have a neural network, you will need to work out the gradient for all $\theta$ at specific value of $\hat{q}(s, a, \theta)$ and use that. At that point, this is the same update rule as regression with the TD Target as the label, so you can just create $x = (s,a)$ and $y$ = (TD Target, calculated anew each time) training pairs, updating a NN with MSE loss as if it were part of a supervised learning problem.